# Firebase gradle build getting error using latest 11.8.0 version

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

Android studio gradle build getting error while using Firebase API. I used all parameter from google doc. It's working with sample application. But if I  am adding the same library to my application gradle build showing this error.

While building gradle it's getting error like this in Android studio 3.0.1.:

```
Error:Cause: inconsistent module metadata found. Descriptor: com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0 Errors: bad group: expected='com.google.gms.' found='com.google.gms'
```

Here I am adding root gradle file:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.3.0-beta4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms.:google-services:3.2.0'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

        maven {
            url 'https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/'
        }

        maven {
            url 'http://maven.localytics.com/public'
        }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And also app gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "co.hushush.user"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.4-Beta"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
        manifestPlaceholders = [appPackageName: "${applicationId}"]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
        pickFirst 'AndroidManifest.xml'

    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    // For easy preference manager
    compile 'com.pixplicity.easyprefs:library:1.9.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0'
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.0'
    compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.9.2006-5'
    compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.8.4'
    compile 'com.localytics.android:library:3.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.asksira.android:loopingviewpager:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.paytm.pgsdk:pgsdk:1.0.6'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.MdFarhanRaja:SearchableSpinner:1.9'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this:

```
'com.google.gms.:google-services:3.2.0'
```

to this:

```
'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
```

there is no `point(.)` before the `:`

Comment: Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzi;
Error:com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzi;

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352591/android-error-converting-byte-to-dex also clean and rebuild

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44455374/errorerror-converting-bytecode-to-dex-multiple-dex-files-define and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949761/unable-to-merge-dex-android-studio-3-0 (there are many links on google about this error)